# Get all parent topics in recursive query in flask with m2m relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables with many to many relationship.

The Topic table is:

| id | name | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mathematics | 0 |
| 2 | Algebra | 1 |
| 3 | Progression | 2 |
| 4 | Number sequences | 3 |
| 5 | Arithmetics | 1 |
| 6 | sum values | 5 |

The task table is

| id | task | topics_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1+2+3+4 | 4 |

tasks_topics table is

| task_id | topics_id |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 |
| 100 | 6 |

THe code of  this database in flask sqlalchemy you can see

```
tasks_topics= db.Table('tasks_topics',
                       db.Column('task_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasks.id')),
                       db.Column('topics_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topics.id'))
                       )

class Tasks(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    task = db.Column(db.Text)

    # связи
    topics = db.relationship('Topics',
                            secondary=tasks_topics,
                            back_populates="tasks")

class Topics(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'topics'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(140))
    parent = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)

    # связи
    tasks = db.relationship('Tasks',
                            secondary=tasks_topics,
                            back_populates="topics")
```

when I query the database,

```
my_task = Tasks.query.options(subqueryload(Tasks.topics)).get(100)
print(my_task.topics)
```

I get the title of only those topics that are especially displayed in the database:

```
[<Topics 3>, <Topics 6>]
```

But my task is to get all parent topics for this request

```
[<Topics 1>, <Topics 2>,<Topics 3>, <Topics 5>, <Topics 6>]
```

Since the database is hierarchical, so the query must be recursive. How should I fix my query to get a different result?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: RDBMS is postgresql

Comment: You will need to construct a completely different query, using CTE on the DB level, and most likely define a `@hybrid_property` to get `all_topics`.